# how to specify rightvalue as null for flexipage UiFormulaCriterion

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, flexipages

How can I pass null value at right side of a UiFormulaCriterion for a flexi page visibility rule criteria. Here is the link for docs - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm
It says that rightvalue for UiFormulaCriterion has to be string.
I want to specify a condition like

```
<criteria>
<leftValue>{!Record.ParentRelation__r.Name}</leftValue>
<operator>EQUAL</operator>
<rightValue>null</rightValue> //have tried here null, nothing(no value just <rightvalue></rightvalue>), $GlobalConstant.Null, $GlobalConstant.EmptyString but none works.
</criteria>
```

As an alternate, I can check for contains also but there too I need negation. i.e. I have to check that the parent relation name should not contain "PR-" because we are starting name of record from PR. This will not be an ideal solution but we will be just ok. Here also I am lacking negation because the operator field has "CONTAINS" and misses negation.

I could also try equating name of parent relation to Id of parent relation (as both will be null so my job will be done) but rightValue does not take variable, it just takes string.

Any luck to get me out of this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the changes online using lighening edit page module and passed nothing in right value. Then I pulled the changes from my scratch org to my local using sfdx pull and it resulted in below-

```
<criteria>
<leftValue>{!Record.ParentRelation__r.Name}</leftValue>
<operator>EQUAL</operator>
</criteria>
```

Post this, I am able to see the result of null condition i.e. Record.ParentRelation__r.Name == null